# What is a good name for this state-like monad

Tags: haskell, monads

This is something of a combination of `State` and `Writer`.  I have checked the monad laws.

```
newtype M s a = M { runM :: s -> (s,a) }

instance (Monoid s) => Monad (M s) where
    return = M . const . (mempty,)
    m >>= f = M $ \s -> 
        let (s' ,x) = runM m s
            (s'',y) = runM (f x) (s `mappend` s')
        in (s' `mappend` s'', y)
```

`StateWriter` seems kinda lame.

Comment: `conat`?  I would have expected `return a = M . flip (,) a` or something like that.

Comment: Why doesn't `>>=` yield `(s \`mappend\` s' \`mappend\` s'', y)`?  I'm just a bit confused about the monoid returned.

Comment: @rampion: having s `mappend` s' `mappend` s'' would mean that runThing f "hello" where f = return () >> return () >> return () would return something like ("hellohellohello",()) wouldn't it?

Comment: @Axman6: Whereas `runM f "hello" where f = return () >> return () >> return ()` is currently `("", ())`, which is also kind of confusing to me.

Comment: @rampion, It's a combination of writer and state. It returns the part of the state that was generated from within the computation.

Answer (score 3):

"Introspective Writer"? It seems that the interesting you can do with it (that you can't do with Writer) is to write an introspect function that examines the state/output and changes it:

```
introspect :: (s -> s) -> M s ()
introspect f = M $ \s -> (f s, ())
```

I can't see that you can do this for writer, I think you'd have to make do with a post-transformer instead:

```
postW :: Writer w a -> (w -> w) -> Writer w a
postW ma f = Writer $ let (w,a) = getWriter ma in (f w,a)
```

Comment: Isn't it what censor :: MonadWriter w m => (w -> w) -> m a -> m a (from Control.Monad.Writer.Class) is for?

Comment: @Ed'ka - yes postW is the same as censor. But both are "post-transformers", the operation on the "log" (w -> w) has to be twinned with a single writer-monad operation. With introspect you can chain it with (>>) in compound monadic expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`Monoidal State`. `MonoState`.`MState`. `AccumState`.

Comment: `AccumState` is nice, maybe `StateAccum`.  That matches what I need it for at least.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe call `SW` (Statefull Writer), I think short names are rather intuitive and save some typing.

Comment: `type SW a b = LongerAndMoreDescriptiveName a b`?

Comment: @rampion: `myFunctionWithVeryLongAndExtremelyDescriptiveName :: Integer -> SomeExtremelyComplicatedDatatypeWhereThisIsTheLongestNameIcanThinkOf -> LongAndDescriptiveMonadT LongerAndMoreDescriptiveName a b` This is why I like short names. - It saves some typing. And for the ones who don't understand the name: RTMF :)

Comment: Read The F*cking Paper (or Read The Functional Pearl :-)

Comment: @luqui: ROFL, you got it exactly. This is what I feel. (For instance when I read some doc like "Arrows according to <some paper> by <some prof>", whithout weblink and just marginal information to the rest.